# How to add grant to Oracle user for insert data in BLOB column

Tags: php, database, oracle, blob

I have a two users oracle `user_1` and `user_2`, `user_1` main user, `user_2` for logs, and in `user_2` have table

```
table_log
(
ID NUMBER,
REPORT_DATE  DATE,
CONTENTS BLOB,
ROW_COUNT    NUMBER
)
```

I want to insert `test.txt` data(json) in blob with `php`, php host and oracle host is difference, and test.txt file is creating php host, when I want to insert test.txt json data in blob, oracle returned is error

```
OCI-Lob::write(): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

code is ok, I have test and live hosts, and in test host it working 100% ok, what grants should be given:

Comment: It has nothing to do with BLOB (as far as I can tell). User, who is inserting data into the table, has to have the INSERT privilege granted by its (table's) owner.

Comment: I always find multi-schema designs just complicate things and cause problems. Does your log table really need its own schema?

Comment: I solved the problem
`GRANT UPDATE ON USER_2.TABLE_LOG TO USER_1;`
I don't have update privilege

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure how to do insert data only but
i had same issue and i just granted all privileges and it solved my issues maybe not best solution but it is one ;)

done by

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO yourUser;
```

based on [oracle tutorial page](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-grant-all-privileges-to-a-user/)

by the way must be done by user that can grant privileges i guess ;)

gl hf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in the table from a different schema then you have to give grants from the table owner schema to the schema which want to do insert/update on the table as follows:

```
-- Execute it from USER2
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON table_log TO USER1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
GRANT UPDATE ON USER_2.TABLE_LOG TO USER_1;
```

...is correct.

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please exlain how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.